# Android Jetpack compose: BackdropScaffold background with GoogleMap corner issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the new BackdropScaffold composable to make a similar looking screen like Google Map with a Map on the back and a list on the front. (See the image)

[image]

As you can see there is a problem with the corner around the front layer. Currently is displayed the surface under (pale blue). What I would like to achieve is having the Google Map shown in those corners. I tried to play with the size and padding of GoogleMap composable or the front panel but no luck.

**UPDATE**

The following example code shows the issue I'm facing. As you can see the BackdropScaffold background is correctly applied (RED). The corners of the front layer are transparent. The issue comes out when you have a different color in your background layer (BLUE). If the background layer contains a map you have the same issue.

BackdropScaffold is dividing the space but not overlaying any layer. The front layer should overlay a bit the back layer to fix this problem.

[image]
[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
internal fun test() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val selection = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val scaffoldState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(BackdropValue.Concealed)
    val frontLayerHeightDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp / 3
    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState) {
        scaffoldState.conceal()
    }
    BackdropScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        appBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Backdrop scaffold") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    if (scaffoldState.isConcealed) {
                        IconButton(onClick = { scope.launch { scaffoldState.reveal() } }) {
                            Icon(Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                        }
                    } else {
                        IconButton(onClick = { scope.launch { scaffoldState.conceal() } }) {
                            Icon(Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                        }
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    var clickCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            // show snackbar as a suspend function
                            scope.launch {
                                scaffoldState.snackbarHostState
                                    .showSnackbar("Snackbar #${++clickCount}")
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.Favorite, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                    }
                },
                elevation = 0.dp,
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        },
        backLayerContent = {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Blue)) {
                items(if (selection.value >= 3) 3 else 5) {
                    ListItem(
                        Modifier.clickable {
                            selection.value = it
                            scope.launch { scaffoldState.conceal() }
                        },
                        text = { Text("Select $it", color = Color.White) }
                    )
                }
            }

        },
        backLayerBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
        frontLayerShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
        headerHeight = frontLayerHeightDp.dp,
        frontLayerBackgroundColor = Color.White,
        frontLayerContent = {
            LazyColumn {
                items(50) {
                    ListItem(
                        text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = "Localized description"
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BackdropScaffold` is creating a `Surface` for from layer under the hood, when you create your own inside `frontLayerContent` it's displayed on top of built-in one.

Instead use `frontLayerShape` and `frontLayerBackgroundColor` parameters:

```
frontLayerShape = BottomSheetShape,
frontLayerBackgroundColor = Color.White,
frontLayerContent = {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(
            items = moorings,
            itemContent = { mooring ->
                ...
            }
        )
    }
}
```

p.s. some comments about your code:

1. When you have `modifier` parameter, you should only apply it for the topmost container in your view - here you've applied it for content of `frontLayerContent`, which may cause unexpected behaviour.
2. You don't need to wrap `LazyColumn` in a `Column` - it has no effect when `Column` has only one child, and if you need to apply a modifier you can do it directly for `LazyColumn`

Comment: Thanks for your improvements Pylyp. I tried your solution and I still have the same result.

Comment: You mentioned to remove the column, I agree but I have some more code other than the LazyColumn, I just updated my code in the question. Thanks for highlight that

Comment: @br00 Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/e2ba49d0d9556703119ef15738cd3271) background color and shape works fine

Comment: Thanks @pylyp I just updated my issue your simpler code. Hopefully is more clear now!

Comment: @br00 ok so originally you haven't used API correctly and I've showed you the way. But now the color visible under the rounded corners is actually `backLayerBackgroundColor` - `BackdropScaffold` was not designed to display some view under the front layer, and even applying `Modifier.offset` to `backLayerContent` is ignored because of how it's built, so I can't think of a way to hack it.

Comment: @br00 At this point I suggest you [let maintainers know](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) about your case - since this component is `ExperimentalMaterialApi` there's a big chance it's gonna be updated after your request

Comment: @br00 I was able to fix it only by forking the component. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dkaera/052230301740b0bd1f4c88493e1186de).
Use a new argument `frontLayerOffset` to set the front layer overflow value.